# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'labels')

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to build a LineChart using chartjs, but I'm running through some issues with reading my data of the chart, It seems that the issue is my lables are null, but I am getting them as an array from dates (checked, and the array is transfered from the server just fine).
I am not sure what the problem is, any idea what could have made the problems??

this is how the chart looks right now:
[image: this is how the chart looks right now]

and I'm getting those several errors:

[image: errors]

Here is my code:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {Chart as chartjs, Title, Tooltip, LineElement, Legend, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement} from "chart.js";

chartjs.register(
  Title, Tooltip, LineElement, Legend, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement
)

function BitCoin() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [dates, setDates] = React.useState(null);
  const [coinValue, setCoinValue] = React.useState(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitcoin")
      .then((res) => res.json()) 
      .then((data) => {

        const twoDimensionArr = data.message;
        setData(twoDimensionArr);               
        setDates(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[0]));    
        setCoinValue(Number(twoDimensionArr.map(item => item[1])));
   })
   .then(console.log(data))
  }, []);

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    lables: dates,
    datasets:[
      {
        lable: "value of BTC in ILS",
        data: coinValue,
        backgroundColor:'gold'
      }
    ]
  })

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center", fontFamily:"Comic Sans MC", fontSize:"100"}}>
      THIS IS THE BitCoin PAGE

      <nav>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
      </nav>

      <nav>
        <Link to="/coins"> Coins </Link>
      </nav>
      
      <Line
      data = {chartData}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default BitCoin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a labels array, in your data object you have a `datasets` key and a `lables` key, this last one is wrong, it is supposed to be `labels`. If you change it to that it will work:

```js
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
  labels: dates,
  datasets: [{
    label: "value of BTC in ILS",
    data: coinValue,
    backgroundColor: 'gold'
  }]
})
```

Same for the `lable` key in the dataset, it is supposed to be `label`

Answer (score -1):

You are writing the spelling of `label` and `labels` incorrect, it should be `label` rather than `lable` and `labels` rather than `lables`. And what other thing I would suggest is wrap you Line component in an condition, like

```
...other code

{ dates.length > 0 && 
  <Line data = {chartData} />
}

...other code
```

This would simply wait for the api call and the `dates` state to change.